# Keep Label on top of TabControl .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tabcontrol, z-order

I have a label that I need to stay on top of my TabControl as I switch from tab to tab.  I have tried calling the Label's BrintToFront method in the SelectedIndexChanged Event of the Tab Control but this has no effect.  I also simply tried right clicking my label in design view and selecting "Bring to Front" but again, this had no effect.

When I switch to my second tab it drops behind the TabControl however, when I go back to my first tab it is in front again.

I placed the label itself on the Form rather than on the TabControl.

I am working in C#.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It would help to know if you're doing WinForm, WPF or some other technology. Also where it the label in relation to the Tab control? Next to the tabs?

Comment: It is on top of the tabs.  Currently it is being hidden behind the TabControl when I switch to my second tab.

Comment: It sounds like when you switch tabs that invalidates the area for the first tab so it would redraw and obscure your label. I'm just guessing here but you could try trapping the change tab event and invalidate your label so that it is forced to redraw. Might be problematic because I'm not sure you have control of the order of the redraws. It's somewhat unusual to put a label over the tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make sure that your label is not located inside a specific tab.  To verify this you need to look at the nesting inside the 'document outline' (ctl+alt+T)

If it is I recommend;
 dragging it just outside the tab control (you can also use the document outline).
 then 'bring it to the front'. 
 and then use the arrow keys, or location property, to move it back into position.

Comment: Using the Arrow Keys worked.  If I drag it over my TabControl and release then it ends up "inside" that particular tab.  But arrowing it over doesn't have this effect.  Thanks.